# Prestashop 1.5 - Create product without tax in PHP

Tags: php, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.5

I have a PHP script that creates a product in PrestaShop. But when I create it, I want it not to be affected by taxes.

How can I do so? Here's what I tried so far:

```
$oProduct->tax_rate = 0;
$oProduct->tax_name = 0;
$oProduct->ecotax = 0;
```

But still, when I go check the created product in the back office, I see default tax rule (19.6%) is selected, instead of "No tax".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out the solution. It's really stupid, but I thought

```
$oProduct->id_tax_rules_group = 0;
```

wouldn't be the solution because I thought the important thing to change was tax rule, and not tax rules group. But it worked. I have these four lines now :

```
$oProduct->id_tax_rules_group = 0;
$oProduct->tax_rate = 0;
$oProduct->tax_name = 0;
$oProduct->ecotax = 0;
```

And it works just fine.

Comment: Do you use prestashop `webservice` to adding products into your prestashop? Because i have some problems with adding products with libraries.

Comment: No, I just made a front controller in my module that creates products.